# Log file related information for Couchbase DB

Tags: logging, couchbase

I am installing the open source version of Couchbase and trying to set the rotation policy for the cluster.

Q1)
[official documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/Trbl-logs.html) doesn't say anything about the log rotation policy apart from debug logs. I want to set a log policy to memcached logs as well as other types of logs present inside the log directory **/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs**

If anyone has configured the same please help. The rotation policy for debug logs is present below.

```
{disk_sink_opts_disk_debug,[{rotation, [{size, 10485760}, 
          {num_files, 10}]}]
```

If anyone can throw some light on memcached logs as well as other type of logs.

Q2) To change the log related setting we need to make changes to **/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config**. I can see there is another file **/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/config**. What is the usage of this file.